# how to create json object in angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, function-parameter

```
this.addToCart = function(id,name,category,price) {
    alert(id+"name"+name);

    var eachProduct = [
        {
            "name": name,
            "id": id,
            "category":category,
            "price":price
        }


    ];
    alert(eachProduct.name);//I am getting undefine
    addedProductsList.push(eachProduct);

    sessionStorage.setItem("addedProductsList", addedProductsList);

    return "success";
};
```

How to pass the function parameters to each product?

Comment: eachProduct is declared as an array, and you have one item in it. Try eachProduct[0].name. If you didn't intend 'eachProduct' to be an array, then remove the square brackets: []; then you can do eachProduct.name.

Answer (score 14):

As Abdul has pointed out you have a JSON array and you want a JSON object, there you need

```
  var eachProduct = 
                     {
                         "name": name,
                         "id": id,
                         "category":category,
                         "price":price
                     };
```

Now `alert(eachProduct.name);` will return name. And I assume by "How to pass the function parameters to the each product" you mean add an attribute to your JSON object. To do this you you would have

```
eachProduct["someAttribute"]='"value":someValue';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `eachProduct` as an array, you need to use `eachProduct[0].name` instead.

Comment: how to push eachProduct array into addedProductList array and how to retrieve it from the storage and get eachProduct name

Comment: did you try `addedProductsList.push(eachProduct[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use forEach to iterate through the array. Please find the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xx8rp/) working on your example.

Snippet of code:

```
eachProduct.forEach(function(obj){
  alert(obj.name);
});
```